# Woocommerce product change color after the upload

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, colors, product

I have a problem with the image of one product in my e-commerce. I am using the WordPress plugin WooCommerce.

The product image has a text with a dark green color, and also when I upload it in order to use in the store it keeps the color.

[image: image uploaded]

[image: original image]

When I select this image as a product image, I don't know why the color of the text change becoming a light green/phosphorescent color.

[image: image after selected as product image]

[image: product image as it shown on the webpage]

I tried to delete and reload the image and even tried to save it with the setting "Save for Web" with Photoshop but I could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to upload both .jpg and .png file and see if it's different ?
I the past i'v had this problem. I fix it by changing the file format/color on my Photoshop sotfware.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Saving it as .png solved my problem!